# Using Arabert model with SpaCy

Tags: nlp, spacy, bert-language-model

SpaCy doesn't support the Arabic language, but Can I use SpaCy with the pretrained Arabert model?

Is it possible to modify this code so it can accept bert-large-arabertv02 instead of en_core_web_lg?

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
```

Here How we can call AraBertV.02

```
from arabert.preprocess import ArabertPreprocessor
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMaskedLM

model_name="aubmindlab/bert-large-arabertv02"
arabert_prep = ArabertPreprocessor(model_name=model_name)  
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

spaCy actually does support Arabic, though only at an alpha level, which basically just means tokenization support (see [here](https://spacy.io/usage/models#languages)). That's enough for loading external models or training your own, though, so in this case you should be able to load this like any HuggingFace model - see [this FAQ](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10768).

In this case this would look like:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank("ar") # empty English pipeline
# create the config with the name of your model
# values omitted will get default values
config = {
    "model": {
        "@architectures": "spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v3",
        "name": "aubmindlab/bert-large-arabertv02"
    }
}
nlp.add_pipe("transformer", config=config)
nlp.initialize() # XXX don't forget this step!
doc = nlp("فريك الذرة لذيذة")
print(doc._.trf_data) # all the Transformer output is stored here
```

I don't speak Arabic, so I can't check the output thoroughly, but that code ran and produced an embedding for me.

Comment: It gives me an error: ValueError: [E002] Can't find factory for 'transformer' for language Arabic (ar). This usually happens when spaCy calls `nlp.create_pipe` with a custom component name that's not registered on the current language class. If you're using a Transformer, make sure to install 'spacy-transformers'. If you're using a custom component, make sure you've added the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components).

Comment: Available factories: attribute_ruler, tok2vec, merge_noun_chunks, merge_entities, merge_subtokens, token_splitter, doc_cleaner, parser, beam_parser, lemmatizer, trainable_lemmatizer, entity_linker, ner, beam_ner, entity_ruler, tagger, morphologizer, senter, sentencizer, textcat, spancat, future_entity_ruler, span_ruler, textcat_multilabel

Comment: I solved it by adding import spacy_transformers